# Add a string into a url python

Tags: python, string, list, url

I am trying to add a string in the middle of an url. Somehow my output looks like this:

```
http://www.Holiday.com/('Woman',)/Beach
http://www.Holiday.com/('Men',)/Beach
```

Somehow it should look like this:

```
http://www.Holiday.com/Woman/Beach
http://www.Holiday.com/Men/Beach
```

The code which I am using looks like the following:

```
list = {'Woman','Men'}
url_test = 'http://www.Holiday.com/{}/Beach'
for i in zip(list):
    url = url_test.format(str(i))
    print(url)
```

Comment: And what do you see printed?

Comment: And Please don't use `list` as a variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this also, And please don't use `list` as a variable name.

```
lst = {'Woman','Men'}
url_test = 'http://www.Holiday.com/%s/Beach'
for i in lst:
     url = url_test %i
     print url
```

Answer (score 6):

Almost there. Just no need for `zip`:

```
items = {'Woman','Men'} # notice that this is a `set` and not a list
url_test = 'http://www.Holiday.com/{}/Beach'
for i in items:
    url = url_test.format(i)
    print(url)
```

The purpose of the `zip` function is to join several collections by the index if the item. When the `zip` joins the values from each collection it places them in a `tuple` which it's `__str__` representation is exactly what you got.
Here you just want to iterate the items in the collection

Comment: Worth mentioning that `list` isn't a good var name and that the `str` (which you removed) was unnecessary

Comment: @brianpck - true :) especially that it is actually a `set`

Comment: @GiladGreen, thanks a lot this what I was looking for. Somehow I misuderstood the use of zip.

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
url = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/top?ref_=nv_mv_250"
html = urlopen(url)

url_list = BS(html, 'lxml')
type(url_list)

all_links = url_list.find_all('a', href=re.compile("/title/tt"))
for link in all_links:
  print(link.get("href"))
all_urls = link.get("href")

url_test = 'http://www.imdb.com/{}/'
for i in all_urls:
    urls = url_test.format(i)
    print(urls)

    this is the code to scrape the urls of all the 250 movies from the main url.
    but the code gives the result as ------

    http://www.imdb.com///
    http://www.imdb.com/t/
    http://www.imdb.com/i/
    http://www.imdb.com/t/
    http://www.imdb.com/l/
    http://www.imdb.com/e/
    http://www.imdb.com///
    and so on ...

    how can i split 'all_urls' using a comma, or how can I make a list of urls in 
    'all_urls'....
```